# Jaxb property exception when set namespacePrefixMapper to define prefix mapping

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb

I am try to set a prefix as below,

```
// Create JAXB Context
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ResultDetails.class);    
            // Create Marshaller
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();    
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new NamespacePrefixMapper() {                    
                @Override
                public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
                    if (TPTConstant.NAMESPACE_SIMPLE_RESULTS.equals(namespaceUri)) {
                        return "psr";
                    }
                    return suggestion;
                }
            });
```

But from setProperty i got a property exception `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper`

I am using java 8 and i already see `jaxb-api 2.3.1` in dependency also. What am i missing here?

Under ResultDetails I already have below defined in each property level.

```
@XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.mycompany.com/services/SimpleResults/data/abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

With property name as `com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper`, this worked